# Missing artifact in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I'm facing a problem in the `pom.xml`. It is showing the below error. I'm trying to update maven by adding the required dependencies but unable to solve the issue .

> Resource   Path    Location    Type Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT pom.xml /spring-security-samples-xml-insecure   line 171    Maven Dependency Problem

Answer (score 0):

SNAPSHOT dependencies are not retrieved by default. If you really need that specific version you will need to add the spring snapshot repository to maven. Usually one relies on released versions only: [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.security%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-security-web%22)

The version you are looking for is in the spring [snapshots repository](https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/).

The maven manual describes how to [work with multiple repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html). Usually people use a repository proxy like Nexus or Artifactory to simplify this.